# WCF Web Service not able to invoke methods in code

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller

I have written WCF Restfull web service and it is working fine , I added reference of it in my one MVC Project and it is working fine ,
but same service reference I added in another MVC project but ,
when creating object  , it is not resolving the service reference correctly

The snippet working fine

```
OLServiceRef.LicenseServiceClient objlocalservice = new OLServiceRef.LicenseServiceClient();
```

Now after this with object **objlocalservice**  i can easily acces methods from my service

Now in another solution when I start with same line it resolve it as

Stock_Reg.OLServiceRef.LicenseServiceClient objlocalservice = new Stock_Reg.OLServiceRef.LicenseServiceClient();

and it start giving me issues ,

I tried configureService Reference  but  Unchecking "Reusetypes in Reference assembly not solved my problem"

In my first application reference gets added in namespace.Service reference name

but in seconde application where it is not working it is as ProjectName.ServiceRefName

Regards,
Pushkar

Comment: It solved my problem  .....
issue was  , In application where I was giving reference of my service
My namespace was not appropriate 
so it was adding my reference correctly but not able to invoke methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved

In application where I was giving reference of my service My namespace was not appropriate so it was adding my reference correctly but not able to invoke methods,
so further if some one face same issue  , make sure namespace are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a service reference to a rest service.

Some client code may get generated but it will not work.

You have to call the service using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) or [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Tom redfern I am not getting u